# Cannot set innerHTML of variable that is outside of fetch()

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am looping over `querySelectorAll` matches using `for()` and the current match is called **meta[i]**. Inside the `for()` function, I'm using `fetch()` to get some information from another page. The problem is that apparently, I can't set the **innerHTML** of **meta[i]** inside the `fetch()` function. Here is my code:

```js
function variations() {
  var meta = item.querySelectorAll('.meta_items tr td:nth-child(1)'), i;
  var id = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < meta.length; ++i) {
    meta[i].querySelector('input').setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    meta[i].querySelector('input').value = id;
    fetch('../public/orders.php?id=' + id).then((resp) => resp.text()).then(function(data) {
      meta[i].innerHTML = data;
    });
  }
}
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefinedat test.js:8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `function` having the `for` cycle adds some AJAX calls which, when answered, their callbacks are called. However, by the time their callbacks are called, your function-scoped `i` has already reached out of bounds due to your for. An extremely simple fix is as follows:

```
function variations() {
  var meta = item.querySelectorAll('.meta_items tr td:nth-child(1)');
  var id = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < meta.length; ++i) {
    meta[i].querySelector('input').setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    meta[i].querySelector('input').value = id;
    fetch('../public/orders.php?id=' + id).then((resp) => resp.text()).then(function(data) {
      meta[i].innerHTML = data;
    });
  }
}
```

I didn't change the way you define your `id`. Is that right to have id = 1 for all the requests and their callbacks?

Comment: It worked perfectly! The `id` value is just for example purposes as I simplified the code before asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think by the time the fetch finished due to `++i`, the value of `i` is `meta.length`. Therefore you are accessing `meta[meta.length]` and this is `undefined`. Try

```
function variations() {
  var meta = item.querySelectorAll('.meta_items tr td:nth-child(1)'), i;
  var id = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < meta.length; ++i) {
    const metaI = meta[i];
    metaI.querySelector('input').setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    metaI.querySelector('input').value = id;
    fetch('../public/orders.php?id=' + id).then((resp) => resp.text()).then(function(data) {
      metaI.innerHTML = data;
    });
  }
}
```